# Scala swing newbie questions

Tags: swing, scala, timer

This is my first experiment using Swing with Scala, and have a few questions about my code below. All it does is to produce a window with a coloured rectangle that changes colour. Please feel free to answer one or any of the questions.

[image: App window]

1) I used a Java ActionListener below because I couldn't work out how to get javax.swing.Timer to work as a Publisher. Is there a way to use the Scala model, i.e. `listenTo()` - or is this the way to do it?

2) My overridden `preferredSize` value in the Panel doesn't seem to work: the window comes up minimized. In my Java version I override the `getPreferredSize` method, but there is no such method in Panel, so I assumed this is the way to do it, but why doesn't it work?

3) `paintComponent` isn't documented at all in the Scala API documentation. I assume this is because it is `protected` access in Java, but it seems like an oversight. Am I correct to override paintComponent or is it hidden because I'm supposed to use the documented `paint` method instead?

4) Scala doesn't seem to have `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods on components - is it standard to use `size.width` and `size.height`?

```
import swing._
import java.awt.{Graphics, Color}
import java.awt.event.{ActionEvent, ActionListener}
import javax.swing.Timer

object ColorPanel extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  private var c: Color = new Color(0)

  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "Flash!"
    contents = p
  }

  val p = new Panel with ActionListener {
    override val preferredSize = new Dimension(200, 200)

    override def paintComponent(g: Graphics2D) {
      g.setColor(c)
      g.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    }

    def actionPerformed(e: ActionEvent) {
      c = new Color((c.getRGB() + 1000) % 16777216)
      repaint
    }
  }

  val timer = new Timer(100, p)
  timer.start()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No immediate answer. But your approach is certainly ok. I don't see though why your observer should be the panel. I would create an anonymous `ActionListener` directly with the timer, and instead add a specific method to that panel, like `def animateColor() { ... }`
2. You can use `preferredSize = new Dimension(200, 200)`
3. According to this quasi official document, yes : http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/8 (section 6 Custom Painting)
4. A bit stupid indeed to instantiate a new `Dimension` all the time. But if you look exactly at the example the SID, it does the same, uses `size.height`. In super high performance code, you may want to call directly into the underlying peer (`peer.getWidth`)